# Could not cast value of type PFObject to PFUser

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I have a tableView populated with an array named matchesResults. I'd like to transition to a view containing details of that object when you tap on the cell. To do this I have set the following function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {       
        self.viewUser = matchesResults[indexPath.row] as! PFUser

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UserSegue", sender: "self.viewUser")
    }
```

However, when I press a cell in the tableView I get the following error:
`Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' to 'PFUser'` on the line above where I define self.viewUser.

If I try to cast it as a PFObject the app won't run and I get an error `Cannot assign a value of type 'PFObject' to a value of type 'PFUser!"`.

How do I get around this?

Thanks!

EDIT: array is created with this query (realMatches is initialized as `[PFObject]`):

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "Match")
            userQuery.whereKey("user1", equalTo: user)

            let userQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "Match")
            userQuery2.whereKey("user2", equalTo: user)

            let currentUserQuery = PFQuery(className: "Match")
            currentUserQuery.whereKey("user1", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            currentUserQuery.whereKey("isActive", equalTo: true)

            let currentUserQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "Match")
            currentUserQuery2.whereKey("user2", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            currentUserQuery2.whereKey("isActive", equalTo: true)

            let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userQuery, userQuery2, currentUserQuery, currentUserQuery2])
            query.includeKey("user1")
            query.includeKey("user2")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                } else {

                    if results != nil {

                        self.matchesResults = results!
                        for result in results!{
                            if result.objectId != self.currentUser!.objectId {
                                self.realMatches.append(result)
```

EDIT 2: segue code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "UserSegue") {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UserViewController
            destinationVC.user = self.viewUser as! PFUser
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error `Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' to 'PFUser'` on the line `destinationVC.user = self.viewUser as! PFUser` when I click on a cell to initiate a segue.

Comment: You are forcing a downcast from PFObject to PFUser which is failing. Unless the objects you stored in your array are PFUsers stored as PFObjects, a downcast will be impossible. Why store a PFObject in PFUser ??

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I initialize the array matchesResults as `[PFObject]`. I then run a Parse.com query and store the results as PFObject, otherwise I get a Segmentation fault 11 error. I updated the code with the query so you can see how the array is created

Comment: How are you initializing self.viewUser?

Comment: `var viewUser: PFUser!`

Comment: Do you create the query object using PFUser.query() method ?

Comment: @james Have you tried not casting as in `self.viewUser = matchesResults[indexPath.row]` so that type inference can work out the details for you?

Comment: I did that and now get an error in my segue code. I think I'm getting closer to a solution! I get `Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' to 'PFUser'` in my segue function which I added to the question above. The error occurs when I run the app and click on a cell to initiate a segue

Comment: I tried using type inference with the segue code like `destinationVC.user = self.viewUser` but I still get the error. Not sure how to fix this since I need the Parse query function to return results as PFObject for it to work from what I've read online

Comment: As I said, you are forcing a downcast from a PFObject to  a PFUser that CANNOT be done ! The objects you get from your query are NOT PFUser objects !! Given that you included `user1` and `user2` in your query results, instead you need to get the user objects by doing `result["user1"] as? PFUser` or `result["user2"] as? PFUser` to get the actual PFUser objects returned by the query.

Comment: I think I understand. I tried doing `self.matchesResults = results! as! [PFUser]` but that didn't work. I created a gist of file here: https://gist.github.com/jtansley/876befc9ad33d617d053

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?